# ILNumerics Grid coordinates with mouse move event in 3D Contour Plot

Tags: ilnumerics

I use the 3D contour plots to create a surface contour.
I want to determine the grid coordinates using the mouse move event, but it does not work in the 3D view. When I double click on the 3D character with the mouse, this is shown flat. I am now looking for a method to determine whether the figure is shown flat in order to determine the proper grid coordinates can.
I want to display a tooltip with the grid coordinates.

In addition, I am looking for a function to the figure by code itself Portray flat.

Code:

```
private void CreateContourPlot(ILArray<float> valueArray)
```

{
    #region CreateContourPlot

```
try
{
    using (ILScope.Enter())
    {
        ILScene scene = new ILScene();

        ILPlotCube plotCube = new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false);
        plotCube.Rotation = Matrix4.Rotation(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), Math.PI / 2);

        ILSurface surface = new ILSurface(valueArray);

        List<ContourLevel> conturLevels = null;
        if (LimitsDrawing)
        {
            conturLevels.Add(new ContourLevel() {Text = string.Empty, Value = LimitMin, LineWidth = 2, LineColor = ConvertColorToFloat(LimitsMinColor)});
            conturLevels.Add(new ContourLevel() {Text = string.Empty, Value = LimitMax, LineWidth = 2, LineColor = ConvertColorToFloat(LimitsMaxColor)});
        }

        if (AverageLineDrawing)
        {
            if (conturLevels == null)
            {
                conturLevels = new List<ContourLevel>();
            }

            conturLevels.Add(new ContourLevel() {Text = string.Empty, Value = AverageLineValue, LineWidth = 3, LineColor = ConvertColorToFloat(AverageLineColor)});
        }

        if (conturLevels != null)
        {
            ILContourPlot contourPlot = new ILContourPlot(valueArray, conturLevels, create3D: true);

            ILLegend legend = new ILLegend();
            contourPlot.Add(legend);

            plotCube.Add(contourPlot);
        }

        surface.Markable = false;
        surface.Fill.Markable = false;
        surface.Wireframe.Markable = false;

        surface.Wireframe.Visible = GridDrawing;

        surface.UseLighting = UsedLight;

        surface.MouseEnter += ILSurface_MouseEnter;
        surface.MouseMove += ILSurface_MouseMove;
        surface.MouseLeave += ILSurface_MouseLeave;

        plotCube.Add(surface);

        scene.Add(plotCube);

        SetSceneToChart(scene);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error in the creating process.\n" + ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
}


#endregion CreateContourPlot
```

}

private void ILSurface_MouseMove(object sender, ILMouseEventArgs e)
{
    #region MouseMove

```
ILGroup group = e.Target.Parent;
if (group != null)
{
    Matrix4 trans = group.Transform;

    while (!(group is ILCamera) && group != null)
    {
        group = group.Parent;
        trans = group.Transform * trans;
    }

    if (group is ILCamera)
    {
        var pos = new Vector3(e.LocationF.X * 2 - 1, e.LocationF.Y * -2 + 1, 0);
        trans = Matrix4.Invert(trans);
        pos = trans * pos;

        toolTipChart.SetToolTip(ilpnlChart, pos);
    }
}


#endregion MouseMove
```

}

[Image view 3D](http://ilnumerics.net/ilcf/41/4910/out.png)
Figure 1 View in 3D

[Image view mouse double click](http://ilnumerics.net/ilcf/7a/0a73/out.png)
Figure 2 View by mouse double-click (flat view)

Comment: Your question is not clear to me yet. Could you post a code example of what you have done so far? What is the expected result? What do you mean by "surface of the mouse movement"?

Comment: I hope the question is now somewhat understandable.

Comment: Is there perhaps a possibility, even in the 3D view to sense the coordinate grid? I would still need this now.

Comment: Felix, I am still facing problems to get the meaning of 'In addition, I am looking for a function to the figure by code itself Portray flat.'

Comment: I want to determine whether the figure in the view, "Default plot Cube View: XY Plane" or "Rotated 3D plot cube" :-D

Comment: You might take a look at the plotcube.Is2DView property. In addition, you could inspect the plotcube.Rotation matrix. There should be no rotational portions (all non- diagonal elements are '0').

Comment: I have already looked at the plotcube.Is2DView property, this is unfortunately always true.

The "plotcube.Rotation matrix" values ​​are always:
1 0 0 0
E-17 6.123032 0 1 0
0 -1 6.123032 E-17 0
0 0 0 1

No matter what position I move PlotCube.

I tried to memorize the display of PlotCube on the mouse double click event, but unfortunately we the event always triggered 2 times, with me still not clear is why!

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the properties on the actual copy of the scene, which is used for rendering? You get that copy via ilPanel1.GetCurentScene(). Mouse interactions do affect that 'local' scene instead of the global one (which may get shared by many drivers).

Comment: The rotation I can now have the method "ILPanel.GetCurrentScene (). <ILPlotCube> First (). Rotational" determine.

Problem I have with the mouse double-click event.
When I attached the event to copy the scene, this is never triggered.
When I attach the event to the scene, this is triggered twice.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This is normal behavior. See the documentation for mouse events: http://ilnumerics.net/mouse-events.html